# What is the best way to communicate between to windows application?

Tags: windows, logging, ipc, message, communication

When designing a central logger application on windows platform.
The several applications will send log message to logger application.
I hope that the logger can accept very big number of logs for a short time.

What is the best way to send log message(or event signal) to the logger?
The logger and clients runs on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Inter-process communication. D-Bus is a good way to communicate between 2 or more processes. On internet you can find several examples of how to implement it in your Windows applications.